# docker service shows an image running but not listed in docker container

Tags: docker

I created a service such like

```
$ docker service create --name psql --secret psql_user --secret psql_pass -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/psql_pass -e POSTGRES_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/psql_user postgres
n48qvp8ulvvk5tp8vwaj7q8fo
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks
1/1: running   [==================================================>]
verify: Service converged
$ docker service ps psql
ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR               PORTS
v3tnzutt0akj        psql.1              postgres:latest     node2               Running             Running 3 minutes ago
```

However, docker container didn't show any image running and unable to exec:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
$ docker exec -it psql bash
Error: No such container: psql
```

Session info:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.11, build 42e35e61f3
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: whta is the output of `docker container ls -a`

Comment: nothing..same as `docker container ls`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the container is crashing on initial boot. Can you start it with the the flag:

```
--restart always
```

And then post output of docker container ls? I suspect it will show up, but be in a state of constant reboot.